# How to create unit test of virtualScroll in table prime Ng

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, primeng, primeng-table

I can't test virtualScroll with lazayload in table

```
  <p-table class="basicTable" [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true" [rows]="100" scrollHeight="500px"
             (onLazyLoad)="load($event)" [rows]="100" lazy="true"
             [virtualScroll]="true">
```

```
  const tableEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.p-datatable-virtual-scrollable-body'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const bodyRows = tableEl.query(By.css('.p-datatable-tbody')).queryAll(By.css('tr'));
    console.log(bodyRows)
```

bodyRows is empty

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Angular teams unit tests provided me an answer to this. There's a number of async steps before the CDK Virtual Scroll displays data, so we have to simulate these. Instead of `fixture.detectChanges()`, add the following function to the top of your `.spec.ts` file and call it while passing the `fixture` as a param:

```js
const finishInit = (fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
  // On the first cycle we render and measure the viewport.
  fixture.detectChanges();
  flush();

  // On the second cycle we render the items.
  fixture.detectChanges();
  flush();

  // Flush the initial fake scroll event.
  tick(500);
  flush();
  fixture.detectChanges();
};
```

Your `it` will also need to use `fakeAsync`

```js
it('should display virtual scroll data', fakeAsync(() => {


}));
```

The above worked with Angular 11 and associed primeNg version. If things have changed and it's not working for you, here's the link to the Angular CDK [virtual scroll unit test](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/15.0.0/src/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.spec.ts#L1194) util method I based this on

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem and this solution didn't help. Still no rows in the unit tests.

Comment: I have the same issue the rows aren't loaded, **bodyRows.length** is always 0, **finishInit** method above doesn't work, any solution?

    const bodyRows = tableEl
            .query(By.css('.p-datatable-tbody'))
            .queryAll(By.css('tr'));
    console.log('bodyRows: ', bodyRows.length);

Comment: I followed your instructions @Drenai but it not work, the data exists but it hasn't be loaded in the table. No matter what i do, always bodyRows is 0.